# dynamic input/output folder location in Camel's file component

Tags: file, apache-camel

As per https://camel.apache.org/file2.html, file component cannot be configured with dynamic input/output folder locations?

Is there any workaround/alternative for the same?

Thanks.

Regards
Senthil Kumar Sekar

Comment: No alternative I know of.

Comment: Output folder location could be dynamic using recipientlist (http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html)

Comment: similar post with solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32655201/3784642

Comment: A solution for dynamic URIs in from() is explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368961/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-from

Comment: similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368961/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-from

Answer (score 3):

**For the file consumer**

You can use a customer filter as dynamic selection of which directories/files to pickup. But the starting directory is configured once (hardcoded).

For that to change you would need to stop the route, and change the directory, and start the route again - if you want to attempt that direction.

**For the file producer**

The file name is fully dynamic you can just set a name as the file header you want. See documentation for details.

Comment: OP wanted a dynamic output *folder* location; only the `fileName` portion of a file endpoint can be dynamic AFAICT.

Comment: Beware that if you build dynamic URIs with the CAMEL FTP/SFTP/FTPS component (v2.16.3, likely other versions) you MUST ensure that all variable parts of the URI are passed as Header properties and not URI options; your URI must be the exactly same (ok with ${} props) with every sending. Indeed, a Dynamic Endpoint is recorded in the Cache for every transmission and if the URI differs by a single char, a new object is allocated. This bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10281 will explode your heap, the documented cache limit (default 1000) is not enforced.

Comment: I wish the comment @berhauz made was in the docs...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the header `CamelFileName` also to dynamically set a directory. Slashes will be turned into directories.

Example: `CamelFileName = "directory/dyn_subdirectory_n/myfilename.txt"` will be placed into the directory `"dyn_subdirectory_n"` located in `"directory"`. The filename will be `"myfilename.txt"`.